# Convert selected dataTable rows to Integer in Cucumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

sample.feature

```
Scenario Outline: My test case
Given: My data is loaded
When : My data is ready
Then: My data is
|name| value    |
|a   | <value1> |
|b   | <value2> |
|c   | <value3> |
|d   | <value4> |

Examples:
|value1| value2|value3| value4 |
|1     | 2     | 3    | text   |
```

steps.js  //using node.js

```
Then('My data is', function (dataTable) {      
  console.log(dataTable);
// console output
   [['a', '1'],
    ['b', '2'],
    ['c', '3'],
    ['d', 'text']]

});
```

I need output as string value as string and Integer as Integer

```
// expected output
       [['a', 1],
        ['b', 2],
        ['c', 3],
        ['d', 'text']]
```

I don't want to hardcode based on name, because It may change. Is there a generic solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect if a value is numeric or not using `isNaN(x)`. If the `isNaN(x)` function returns `false`, you can safely ignore that value in the cucumber data table. If the `isNaN(x)` function returns `true` then you can use the `Number(x)` function to convert the string to a number.

The `isNaN` and `Number` functions are complimentary. For any given input, if `isNaN` returns `true`, then passing that same input to `Number` will return a `NaN` value. If `isNaN` returns `false` then passing that input to `Number` will successfully convert it to a Number.

Remember that zero is a falsey value in JavaScript, so `if (Number("0"))` will be evaluate to `false`.

```
function parseDataTable(dataTable) {
  return dataTable.map((row, index) => {
    if (!isNaN(row[1])) {
      row[1] = Number(row[1]);
    }

    return row;
  });
}
```

And to use it in your step definition:

```
Then('My data is', function (dataTable) {      
  dataTable = parseDataTable(dataTable);

  console.log(dataTable);

  /*
    Should output:
    [
      ["a", 1],
      ["b", 2],
      ["c", 3],
      ["d", "text"]
    ]
  */
});
```

Comment: What if i need value3 number as string Examples: |value1| value2|value3| value4 | |1 | 2 | '3' | text | // expected output [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', '3'], ['d', 'text']]

Answer (score 0):

This would be a language specific problem. This could be solved by using an object mapper. In javascript I think there is a `#map` function (But I'm not 100%). So you would want something like.

My JS is really rusty though

EDIT: Better solution is:

```
const ans = array2.map((array, index) => {
  return array.map((element, innerIndex) => {
    retVal = innerIndex%2==0 ? element + 1 : element * 2
    return retVal
  })
})
```

This will take each element of the inner array, and add 1 to it if it is a value at position 0,2,4 e.t.c. and multiply by 2 if it's position 1,3,5 e.t.c.

You can modify it to your own requirements.